# How can I convert List<Item> to Map<Datetime, List<Item>> in dart / Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, hashmap, type-conversion

I have a list of difined Todo items like:

```
Todo{
 Datetime datetime;
 String task;
}
```

List todos = [todo1, todo2,...]

And I need to convert it to a map with type `Map<Datetime, List<String>>` , but in todos list, I have some todo with the same Datetime so when I use code like:

`todos.forEach((todo) => map2[todo.datetime] = todo.task);` the next todo will be replaced if the key is the same.

So sorry if this is a silly question, I have searched on Google but nothing there.
Thanks,
Hung PT.

Comment: use `groupBy` top level function

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response, base on your recommendation I have found a package it's named collection: ^1.14.13 which solve my problem.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
todos.forEach((todo) => map2[todo.datetime] = map2[todo.datetime] == null ? [...map2[todo.datetime], todo.task] : [todo.task]);
```

Comment: Thank for your response, last night I have found the package named collection: ^1.14.13 , and use the groupBy function that solve my problem.